# Where to place init code with Angular 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular web application that is currently calling the backend API every time I need to display the user name or user image. However, I would now like to be able to cache this information in localStorage when the application is first started. What would be the best way or best place to do this in Angular? I image it would be something equivalent to the jquery `$(document).ready` method. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could put it in the [run block](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks). This will run once when your app starts up

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function () {
    //Run init code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `module.run` for this, a better option would be a thematically related service. Angular services are created once, and so you can just put your loading code on the top level.

E.g.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('currentUser', function() {
    // load user data from local storage, if not found load from server
    // then store in localStorage

    this.name = /* loaded name */;
    // etc...

});
```

Note that most of requests are asynchronous, so you might want to do a `factory` that would return a user promise instead.

Comment: I would be tempted to combine the usage of `service` and `run`. Firstly I would create a service that can help me with the CRUD operations for caching, and then I would call this service class from within the angular run method.